# counter starting from 0 after pause

Tags: typescript

Trying to create count-up timer but it is starting from 0 after pausing the counter. what is causing the issue?

Here is typescript code. Am new to typescript so any help can be appreciated.

```
  export class TrackPage {
  newTime;
  interval;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private walkingProvider: WalkingProvider) {
    console.log(navParams.get("myVal"));
    this.newTime= walkingProvider.getNewTime();

    if (navParams.get("myVal") == "true") {

      this.startTimer();

    }

  }

  startTimer() {

  let seconds=0;
  let minutes=0;
  let hours=0;
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      seconds++;
      if (seconds == 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;

        if (minutes == 60) {
          minutes = 0;
          hours++;
        }
      }

      this.newTime= hours == 0 ? this.pad2(minutes) + ":" + this.pad2(seconds) : this.pad2(hours) + ":" + this.pad2(minutes) + ":" + this.pad2(seconds);
    }, 1000)
  }

  pauseTimer() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.walkingProvider.setNewTime(this.newTime);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move below variable outside of `startTimer()` function and that should work.

```
let seconds=0;
let minutes=0;
let hours=0;
```

Why is that required? So whenever you make call to `startTimer()` function, variables like `seconds`, `minutes` and `hours` is being set to `0`. 
Once you move those variable outside that function, it should work. Once more thing, if you want to reset timer/counter to `0`, you can create new function like `resetTimer()` where you can set variables like `seconds`, `minutes` and `hours` to `0`.